# Eclipse not able to locate class files in jars present in build path

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to remove errors from my newly created Eclipse Indigo workspace. Following the normal process i am adding all the dependent project to the build path of different projects. To reduce the build time i created the jar of all the projects where i am sure i am not going to make changes but i need them for dependency. But the problem is as soon as i remove the actual project from the build path and add a jar of the same project. My eclipse fails to search the imported java files from the jar.

Say for example :

P1, P2, P3 as projects where i need P1 and P2 as dependency for P3. And i am sure that i will not make any changes in P1 and P2. When i add P1 and P2 to P3 build path everything is fine. But when i remove P1 and P2 and add the corresponding jars to the build path the errors reappear.

I have tried all the workarounds like refreshing, rebuilding, adding and removing etc.

Why is eclipse not able to scan the jars for imports??

Comment: Did you try refresh/clean all/build all? Or closing the P3 and reopening it? Are you sure the jars containg all the rqeuired classes?

Comment: In addition to A4L questions: Are you sure that you jars are valid? How did you build them?

Comment: I build them from eclipse itself using the export option.

Comment: Have you tried to manage the process manually, via command line? Cause it may be some Eclipse-specific issue...